# java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "@MYIPADDRESS, when using android + mongodb

Tags: java, android, mongodb, android-asynctask

I have created a MongoClientURI like this:

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI( "mongodb://User_name:Password@MyIPAddress:27017/"+TEST_SKETCH_APP );

        MongoClient instance = MongoDatabaseConnection.getInstance(uri);
        DB db = instance.getDB(uri.getDatabase());
        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection(SKETCH_COLLECTION);

        BasicDBObject  dbObject = new BasicDBObject();

        dbObject.put("name", url[0]);
        dbObject.put("password", url[1]);
        dbObject.put("email", url[2]);
        dbObject.put("phoneNumber", url[3]);

        collection.insert(dbObject);
```

And I am calling this method from AsyncTask :

```
@Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return saveValues(urls);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  null;
    }
```

I also have all permissions required for internet connection too:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

But still I am not able to insert values to the database running in that IP address. 
The full error says :

```
Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}.
Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=@MYIPADDRESS:27017,
 type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: 
 Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: 
 Unable to resolve host "@MYIPADDRESS": No address associated with hostname}, 
 caused by {android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: 
 EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)}}]
```

I know the IP ADDRESS is correct as I can type this in chrome `http://MYIPADDRESS:27017/`

And got this in return:

`It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.`

Comment: You have to put actual data in MongoClientURI argument url. Try replacing username, password and myipaddress with its actual values

Comment: I have used in my code, but not pasted here. I cannot paste my IP address here.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I was getting the same error. I was trying to connect statically, but you need to do it in the constructor.